# What is the limit of a sequence defined recursively as $x_1=2$, $x_{n+1}=\frac{1}{3-x_n}$ with $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and how do I prove it exists?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

This is an exercise I've found online.

> Find the limit of a sequence defined recursively as $x_1=2$, $x_{n+1}=\dfrac{1}{3-x_n}$ with $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Show that the limit exists before attempting to find it.

So far, I have shown that $\{x_{n}\}$ is bounded below by $0$ and above by $2$ since $\frac{1}{3-x_n}>0$ and $\frac{1}{3-x_n}\le 2$ for all $n$.

I'm stuck here because I'm not sure what to show next, and I don't know precisely how to show the limit exists.

Comment: Show that $(x_n)$ is a decreasing sequence and then appeal to the fact that a bounded monotone sequence is convergent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first, you can show that $x_1>x_2$ easily.

If $x_{n-1}>a_n$ holds (and $0\le x_n \le 2$ for all $n$), we get
$$\begin{align}
x_{n-1}>x_n & \Longrightarrow & -x_{n-1}<-x_n \\
 & \Longrightarrow & 3-x_{n-1}<3-x_n \\
 & \Longrightarrow & \frac{1}{3-x_{n-1}}>\frac{1}{3-x_n} \\
 & \Longrightarrow & x_n > x_{n+1}\\
\end{align}$$

so $x_n>x_{n+1}$. So this sequence convergent, by monotone convergence theorem.

Comment: Is this an inductive proof that $x_{n}>x_{n+1}$?

Comment: @Limitless Oh, it is my mistake.

Comment: In the last line, how do you arrive at $x_n>x_{n+1}$? Isn't $\dfrac{1}{3-x_{n-1}}=x_{n}$? By definition, if $x_{n+1}=\dfrac{1}{3-x_{n}}$, then a substitution of $x=x'-1$ shows us that $x_{n}=\dfrac{1}{3-x_{n-1}}$.

Comment: @DavidMitra I do not follow his or her progression from line 3 to line 4. Is it correct? If so, why?

Comment: @Limitless Line 3 had a typo. It is now correct.

Comment: @David Mitra thanks for points out mistake in my proof.

Comment: @DavidMitra Yeah, that's what I wasn't seeing. Thank you. It took me a second to realize $x<y\implies \frac{1}{x}>\frac{1}{y}$ in general.

Answer (score 2):

For limit solve the equation $$l=\frac{1}{3-l} \implies l^2-3l+1=0$$ You get $l=\frac{3+\sqrt 5}{2},\frac{3-\sqrt 5}{2}$. Your limit will be  $\frac{3-\sqrt 5}{2}$ since $\frac{3
+\sqrt 5}{2} >2$.

Answer (score 2):

If a limit $L$ exists, it must satisfy
$$x_{n+1} = \frac{1}{3-x_n}
\Rightarrow L = \frac{1}{3-L}
\Rightarrow L^2-3L+1=0$$

So that candidates for the limit are $\frac{3\pm \sqrt{5}}{2}$. Since you've proven the series is bounded above by 2, only one of these is possible.